# Postman issues with sharepoint API

Tags: api, sharepoint

Im getting the grant type error on connecting to sharepoint api.
Grant type is already specified in my body.
Any suggestion on how to fix this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should add the query parameters to the request body:

[image]